# Update select value for antd form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd

I am currently fetching information from an API endpoint and updating the values of an [antd Form component](https://ant.design/components/form/#header). I am able to update values for numeric and text inputs using `setFieldsValue()` but for selects things are a bit more complicated. My code currently looks like this:

```
<Form
  {...layout}
  name="basic"
  initialValues={{ remember: true }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
  onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
  form={form}
>
  [... Other form items removed for simplicity]
  <Form.Item
    label="NFT Status"
    name="nftStatus"
  >
    <Select defaultValue="not-minted" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleNftStatusChange}>
      <Option value="minted">Minted</Option>
      <Option value="not-minted">Not minted</Option>
      <Option value="sold">Sold</Option>
    </Select>
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item
    label="Controls"
  >
    <Button style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>Cancel</Button>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

And this is the code used to update the form values:

```
async function getCollectible(tokenId, contractAddress) {
  try {
    const asset = await seaport.api.getAsset({
      tokenAddress: contractAddress,
      tokenId: tokenId,
    });

    const getNftStatus = () => {
      if (asset.numSales !== 0) {
        return 'sold';
      } else if (asset.numSales === 0 && asset.orders.length === 0) {
        return 'not-minted';
      } else {
        return 'minted';
      }
    };

    // Write information from response into form inputs
    form.setFieldsValue({
      artworkName: asset.name,
      description: asset.description,
      externalLink: asset.externalLink,
      artist: asset.owner.address,
      nftStatus: getNftStatus(),
      price: asset.lastSale ? (asset.lastSale.totalPrice / 1000000000000000000) : ''
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

All input values are properly set when running the `getCollectible()` function that uses `form.setFieldsValue()`, except for the select. I'm not sure how to update its value programatically. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `Select` where the issue is? If you try to do `artist: getNftStatus()`, what do you get there?

Comment: Also, instead of using `defaultValue` you could do `initialValues={{ remember: true, nftStatus: 'not-minted' }}`

Comment: @alextrastero I'm most certain this isn't a race/async condition, because if I log getNftStatus inside the getCollectibles function, I get the expected string (minted/not-minted/sold)

Comment: Have you determined if it's a `Select` issue? or does it also happen with `Input`?

Comment: Yes, it's exclusively happening with `Select`, `Input` works just fine.

Comment: Here's a working example, seems it was not a race/async issue, https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bohr-wqfo5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I would think this is some async issue. Try extracting the `getNftStatus` and adding `asset` as an argument.

```
const getNftStatus = (asset) => {
  if (asset.numSales !== 0) {
    return 'sold';
  } else if (asset.numSales === 0 && asset.orders.length === 0) {
    return 'not-minted';
  } else {
    return 'minted';
  }
}

async function getCollectible(tokenId, contractAddress) {
  try {
    const asset = await seaport.api.getAsset({
      tokenAddress: contractAddress,
      tokenId: tokenId,
    });

    // Write information from response into form inputs
    form.setFieldsValue({
      artworkName: asset.name,
      description: asset.description,
      externalLink: asset.externalLink,
      artist: asset.owner.address,
      nftStatus: getNftStatus(asset),
      price: asset.lastSale ? (asset.lastSale.totalPrice / 1000000000000000000) : ''
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To select an option, the term "selected" needs to be added to the HTML tag

```
<option value="value" selected >Option Name</option>
```

This can be dynamically handled in React by storing the form data to a state (eg:foo), followed by below code

```
 <Select defaultValue="not-minted" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleNftStatusChange}>
  <Option value="minted" {foo.nftStatus === "minted"?"selected":""} >Minted</Option>
  <Option value="not-minted" {foo.nftStatus === "not-minted"?"selected":""} >Not minted</Option>
  <Option value="sold"  {foo.nftStatus === "sold"?"selected":""}>Sold</Option>
</Select>
```

Comment: I think `ant design` already handles this, calling `setFieldsValue` should be able to handle a `Select` if there's a valid `Option` with that value.

Comment: thats wrong, there's no need to add 'selected' in antd